# Can you help James Bond find the next letter?

Tags: knowledge, sequence, movies, letter-sequence

James Bond needs to hack into Le Chiffre's computer to prevent him from fulfilling his evil plan.

All he needs to do is find the next letter in this sequence:

> H O T T S F F F S

Question: Can you help him find the next letter in the sequence (if there is one)?

Keep trying until you get it!

Answer (score 15, accepted):

I think the next letter is

> R

Reasoning

> These are the initial letter of poker hands ranked weakest to strongest:
>  **H**igh Card.
>  **O**ne pair.
>  **T**wo pair.
>  **T**hree of a Kind.
>  **S**traight.
>  **F**lush.
>  **F**ull House.
>  **F**our of a Kind.
>  **S**traight Flush.
>  and finally
>  **R**oyal Flush

Comment: Looks correct to me!

Comment: ROT13: Nqqvgvbany pyhrf: Gur vavgvnyf bs rnpu yvar naq gur ersrerapr gb gur zbivr Pnfvab Eblnyr.